# Cannot read property 'target' of undefined Function remove not working

Tags: javascript

I have an array that has 3 contacts. I want the same person's name to be deleted when I click on the delete button, but unfortunately I do not know where the problem is that it does not work.
I have two functions in this program, one `removeContact` to perform the delete operation
And I have a function called `showrecords` to get the content of the array and display the name and number of contacts with a dedicated delete button for each contact
In this program, I used the pattern builder pattern
Please guide me to the conclusion to solve the problem of not being deleted

*Please click on the show Person button to test the program. Contacts will be displayed and click on the delete button. You will see that the delete operation is not performed.*

```js
function ElementBuilder(name) {
    this.element = document.createElement(name);

    this.appendSelector = function(selector) {
        this.appendElement = document.querySelector(selector).appendChild(this.element);
        return this
    };

    this.setAttribute = function(attribute, valueAttribute) {
        this.element.setAttribute(attribute, valueAttribute)
        return this;
    };

    this.addEventListener = function(event, fun) {
        this.element.addEventListener(event, fun);
        return this;
    };

    this.text = function(text) {
        this.element.textContent = text;
        return this;
    };

    this.build = function() {
        return this.element;
    };
}

const builder = {
    create: function(name) {
        return new ElementBuilder(name);
    }
};

function PhoneBook() {

    this.records = [{ name: "niloufar", phone: 1111 }, { name: "sara", phone: 2222 }, { name: "sara", phone: 3333 }];

    // function remove

    this.removeContact = function() {
        const self = this

        function removePerson(item) {
            if (item.target.classList.contains('delbutton')) {
                const remID = item.target.getAttribute('data-id');
                self.records.splice(remID, 1);
            }
        }
        return removePerson;
    }
}

function Render(container) {
    this.container = container;
    const phoneBook = new PhoneBook();

    const remove = phoneBook
        .removeContact();

  this.removeEntry = (item) => { 
    remove(item); // 
    this.showrecords();
}
    this.init = function() {
        const btn = builder
            .create("button")
            .text("show person")
            .addEventListener("click", this.showrecords)
            .appendSelector("div")
            .build();
    };
    // Function: Read contacts from the array and display them
    this.showrecords = () => {
        const addBookId = document.getElementById('phone-book-container');
        let index = 0;
        addBookId.innerHTML = '';
        const arry = phoneBook.records;
        arry.forEach(elm => {
            const nameContent = builder
                .create('p')
                .text(`${elm.name}`)
                .appendSelector("div")
                .build();
            const phoneContent = builder
                .create('p')
                .text(`${elm.phone}`)
                .appendSelector("div")
                .build();
            const anchor = builder
                .create('a')
                .addEventListener('click', this.removeEntry)
                .setAttribute('href', '#')
                .setAttribute('class', 'delbutton')
                .setAttribute("id", "deleteButton")
                .text("delete")
                .setAttribute('date-id', `${index}`)
                .appendSelector("div")
                .build();
        });

    }
}
const phoneBookContainer = document.getElementById("phone-book-container");
const app = new Render(phoneBookContainer);
app.init();
```

```html
  <div id="phone-book-container"></div>
```

Comment: Please help me I'm confused :(

Comment: `removePerson` expects an `item` but you never seem to pass this argument to your function: `(this.removeEntry = () => { remove() ...` so item ends up `undefined`.

Comment: @OtherMe No my friend this is my first question please help me if you know

Comment: is data-id storing the index of the person?

Comment: @ĐinhCarabus Can you please edit my code? I did not understand what you mean !!!

Comment: @FireFighter yes

Comment: @good there is a duplicate question with near identical code by the user 'goodboy' is this you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67097383/cannot-read-property-target-of-undefined-in-function-remove

Comment: @ĐinhCarabus Please help me, I am very, very confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the `item` (which is actually the `event` object) to your function:

```js
function ElementBuilder(name) {
    this.element = document.createElement(name);

    this.appendSelector = function(selector) {
        this.appendElement = document.querySelector(selector).appendChild(this.element);
        return this
    };

    this.setAttribute = function(attribute, valueAttribute) {
        this.element.setAttribute(attribute, valueAttribute)
        return this;
    };

    this.addEventListener = function(event, fun) {
        this.element.addEventListener(event, fun);
        return this;
    };

    this.text = function(text) {
        this.element.textContent = text;
        return this;
    };

    this.build = function() {
        return this.element;
    };
}

const builder = {
    create: function(name) {
        return new ElementBuilder(name);
    }
};

function PhoneBook() {

    this.records = [{ name: "niloufar", phone: 1111 }, { name: "sara", phone: 2222 }, { name: "sara", phone: 3333 }];

    // function remove

    this.removeContact = function() {
        const self = this

        function removePerson(item) {
            if (item.target.classList.contains('delbutton')) {
                const remID = item.target.getAttribute('date-id');
                self.records.splice(remID, 1);
            }
        }
        return removePerson;
    }
}

function Render(container) {
    this.container = container;
    const phoneBook = new PhoneBook();

    const remove = phoneBook
        .removeContact();

    this.removeEntry = (item) => {
        remove(item);
        this.showrecords();
    }
    this.init = function() {
        const btn = builder
            .create("button")
            .text("show person")
            .addEventListener("click", this.showrecords)
            .appendSelector("div")
            .build();
    };
    // Function: Read contacts from the array and display them
    this.showrecords = () => {
        const addBookId = document.getElementById('phone-book-container');
        
        addBookId.innerHTML = '';
        const arry = phoneBook.records;
        arry.forEach((elm, index) => {
            const nameContent = builder
                .create('p')
                .text(`${elm.name}`)
                .appendSelector("div")
                .build();
            const phoneContent = builder
                .create('p')
                .text(`${elm.phone}`)
                .appendSelector("div")
                .build();
            const anchor = builder
                .create('a')
                .addEventListener('click', this.removeEntry)
                .setAttribute('href', '#')
                .setAttribute('class', 'delbutton')
                .setAttribute("id", "deleteButton")
                .text("delete")
                .setAttribute('date-id', `${index}`)
                .appendSelector("div")
                .build();
        });

    }
}
const phoneBookContainer = document.getElementById("phone-book-container");
const app = new Render(phoneBookContainer);
app.init();
```

```html
  <div id="phone-book-container"></div>
```

Comment: I edited my code the way you did, but when I clicked the button
  Delete the middle person, I click, the first person is deleted, but the middle person must be deleted !!!!

Comment: When I click on the Delete Last Person button, the first person is deleted.

Comment: Thanks for helping me

Comment: @good, I fixed that now. Your indexing was wrong. Each item had the same ID of `0`. Also there was a typo (`data-id` instead of `date-id`). Check out the updated code.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Thank you very much